# Google App Engine many-to-many to self

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, nosql, non-relational-database

I'm trying to convert a django project for GAE, and I've stumbled upon this:

```
(relational-databse)

class Clan(models.Model):
    wars = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

How can I do this in a non-relational database(i.e. gae datastore)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect more than, say, a couple of hundred keys in the list of related entities, you could use a db.ListProperty(db.Key), containing the keys of the referenced entities.